# Serving a static html page using flask, with a parameter

Tags: reactjs, flask

Ive created a simple react application, and ive created the static html files using

```
npm run build
```

In order to serve them using flask, im just doing:

```
@app.route('/')
def serve():
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')
```

In my react app, i give the user an option to enter a date, and load some data related to this date.

What i want to do is - give the user an option to enter a URL with a date, and load that html with the data directly. e.g:

url = host_address/2021-01-04
which will load the same index html page, but with the data for that given date already loaded

But im loading static html pages, how can i somehow pass the date param to the html im going to load?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
@app.route('/')
def serve():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

and keep the index.html in templates folder in the flask file structure